# Iterate through a list, and convert string “numbers” to integers

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to convert the numbers in the list from strings to integers, while leaving other strings unchanged.

I have prepared the following code, however I am receiving an error saying, “argument of type ‘int’ is not iterable”.

Why is this not working, or what would be a better way of going about this?

```
test_list = ['the','dog','ran','down','984','47','the','chicken','4','77']
numSet = '0123456789'


for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
    for j in numSet:
        if j in test_list[i]:
            test_list[i]=int(test_list[i])

print(test_list)
```

Comment: `new_list = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in test_list ]`?

Comment: @Chris, don't use `isdigit()`, use `isdecimal()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
test_list = ['the','dog','ran','down','984','47','the','chicken','4','77']
numSet = '0123456789'


for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
    for j in numSet:
        if j in str(test_list[i]):
            test_list[i]=int(test_list[i])

print(test_list)
```

Use this, in the list the numeric values are noted as int's

As the characters would be recognized as integers, first it would convert them to string and then it would be checked for the character. For an example if you take thec case of 47, numset would try to check for 0 in 47 (In numeric values, btw in operation checks for values within a string). So I guess it would sum up the case for you

Comment: It would be better if you could give a little explanation with this `str(test_list[i])`

Comment: As the characters would be recognized as integers, first it would convert them to `string` and then it would be checked for the character. For an example if you take thec case of 47, numset would try to check for `0` in `47` (In numeric values, btw `in` operation checks for values within a string). So I guess it would sum up the case for you

Comment: Please add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
test_list = [int(test_list[i]) if test_list[i].isdecimal() else test_list[i] for i in range(len(test_list))]
```

The above code sample converts the numbers to integers keeping the strings untouched.

Comment: `test_list = [int(i) if i.isdecimal() else i for i in test_list]`

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list = ['the','dog','ran','down','984','47','123.45','chicken','4','77']

test_list_temp=[]
for item in test_list:
    try:
        int(item)
        test_list_temp.append(int(item))
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            float(item)
            test_list_temp.append(float(item))
        except Exception as e:
            test_list_temp.append(item)
```

This would however fail to catch something like "³"

Comment: `isinstance('4', int)` will return `False`, which is not the desired behavior of OP

Comment: `if item.isdecimal() int(item) elif item.count(".") == 1 and item.replace(".", "").isdecimal() float(item) else item`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `str.isdecimal` which tells you if a string is a digit. So `'12'.isdecimal()` is `True` but `'A12'.isdecimal()` is `False`. Possible solution:

```
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    if test_list[i].isdecimal():
        test_list[i] = int(test_list[i])
```

Note that if an element is a float, e.g. `'1.234'`, it will not be converted.

Edit: Replaced `isdigit` with `isdecimal` as per a comment below.

Comment: `"³".isdigit()` will return True.

Comment: Never realized this, thanks! Will edit my answer now.